# How can I create a list header that shows and hides as you scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'd like to create a header on a gridView that slides out as I scroll down to not show (giving the grid view more space)  and if I scroll back up slides back into view.

You can see this behaviour on Twitter's android app and on Google+. I've looked around for some libraries but can't see anything that's what I'm looking for.

The key is that it must work with a grid view, and reveal more content when it hides, not simply overlay the content.